# Opposite of String.Split with separators (.net)

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string

Is there a way to do the opposite of `String.Split` in .Net? That is, to combine all the elements of an array with a given separator.

Taking `["a", "b", "c"]` and giving `"a b c"` (with a separator of `" "`).

**UPDATE:** I found the answer myself. It is the `String.Join` method.

Comment: I have forgotten, searched for, and found this question / answer 3 times now in the last year.

Comment: This can get confusing, since LINQ gives `string[]` a Join method that does something completely different.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Found the answer. It's called [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Join(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 21):

You can use [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Join(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] array = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
string separator = " ";
string joined = String.Join(separator, array); // "a b c"
```

Though more verbose, you can also use a [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) approach:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

if (array.Length > 0)
{
    builder.Append(array[0]);
}
for (var i = 1; i < array.Length; ++i)
{
    builder.Append(separator);
    builder.Append(array[i]);
}

string joined = builder.ToString(); // "a b c"
```

Answer (score 0):

> using string.join():

```
string[] array = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
string separator = ",";
string joined = String.Join(separator, array); // "a,b,c"
```

> using StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder namesSB = new StringBuilder();
namesSB.AppendJoin(separator, array);
string joined =namesSB.ToString();
```