# how to get multiple value from an array into string separate by comma

Tags: iphone, ios

i was trying to insert a string into database having multiple value using componentsSeparatedByString:@",". I am getting all the values in "arrayp1net" but problem is how to make a string that contains all the values of array "arrayp1net" separated by comma (,)?

```
if(p1h < 18)
{
    for(int k=0;k<[arrayp1 count];k++)
    {
        if([[hcar1 objectAtIndex:1]intValue] >= [[ar33 objectAtIndex:k] intValue])
        {
            NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[[arrayp1 objectAtIndex:k] text] intValue] -1];
            [arrayp1net addObject:str];        
           }
        else
        {
            NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[[arrayp1 objectAtIndex:k] text]intValue]];
            [arrayp1net addObject:str];
            player1netscore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",arrayp1net];
        }
    }
```

yes i need the same but i have to insert in database in one row of a column with query, so that when i am going to fetch, i fetch all as it is.

```
query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into normalscoring  
(gameid,coursename,p1,p2,p3,p4,p1s,p2s,p3s,p4s,gameDate,p1nets,p2nets,p3nets,p4nets)  
 values (\'%@\',\'%@\',\'%@||%@\',\'%@||%@\',\'%@||%@\',\'%@||%@\',
 ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,||0||0||0||0',
 ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,||0||0||0||0',
 ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,||0||0||0||0',
 ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,||0||0||0||0',
  \'%@\',',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,',
 ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,',',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,',',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,')",
 txtgameid.text,txtcoursename.text,txtplayer1.text,player1handicap,
 txtplayer2.text,player2handicap,txtplayer3.text,player3handicap,
txtplayer4.text,player4handicap,txtdate.text];
```

here is what i am trying to do after if statement but getting exception

```
player1netscore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",arrayp1net];
arn11=[player1netscore componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
player1netscore=[[arn11 objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"p1nets"];
NSLog(@"player1netscore...%@",player1netscore);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`-[NSArray componentsJoinedByString:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/componentsJoinedByString%3a):

```
NSString *stringp1net = [arrayp1net componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Comment: do you know how to do it in android.? if not known then can you refer to any android developer so that i can ask about it.

Comment: I know how to search stackoverflow... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978933/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-join-array-elements-with-a-separator-the-oposite-of-spl

Answer (score 0):

I am not really clear about what you want.....but whatever I got from your question is you want a string which will contain the elements of arrayp1net array which will be comma seprated

```
     NSString *str = @"";    
   for(int i = 0; i< [arrayp1net count]; i++){

          str = [str stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[arrayp1net objectAtIndex:i]]];

      }
```

For this your arrayp1net should be NSMutable array.