# Avoid printing the last comma

Tags: java

I'm trying to print this loop without the last comma. I've been Googling about this and from what i've seen everything seems overcomplex for such a small problem. Surely there is an easy solution to avoid printing the last comma. Much appreciated if somebody could help me out, this is driving me insane!!!

For example it loops from 1-10 // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, < do not want this last comma

```
public static void atob(int a,int b)
{
    for(int i = a; i <= + b; i++) 
    {
        System.out.print(i + ",");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a While loop instead... or perhaps put it all into a single string and then use substring of the length -1

Comment: You could use some book http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076580/recommend-an-algorithms-exercise-book

Comment: Forgot to mention...i have to loop using for because the teacher said so...definitely not in a good spot.

Comment: @OMGjava mate i dont think sitting there and refreshing this page will serve the motivation of homework

Comment: Yes, i wish it was that simple @kommradHomer

Comment: possible duplicate of [A quick and easy way to join array elements with a separator (the oposite of split) in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978933/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-join-array-elements-with-a-separator-the-oposite-of-spl)

Answer (score 13):

I might get stoned to death for this answer

```
public static void atob(int a,int b) {
  if(a<=b) {
    System.out.println(a);
      for(int i = a+1;i<=b;i++) {
        System.out.println(","+i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why, it's the way I'd do it.  It just needs a range check for a prior to outputting a.

Answer (score 6):

Yet another way to do this.

```
String sep = "";
for(int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    System.out.print(sep + i);
    sep = ",";
}
```

if you are using a StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    sb.append(i).append(',');
System.out.println(sb.subString(0, sb.length()-1));
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
public static void atob(int a,int b)
{
    for(int i = a; i < b; i++) 
    {
            System.out.print(i + ",");
    }
    System.out.print(b); 
}
```

Comment: if A is greater than B then it still prints A.

Comment: This won't compile as the variable `i` is out of scope in the last print statement.

Comment: Thanks for giving me perspective to this!

Answer (score 4):

Java 8:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(a, b)
         .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

---

If you want to perform interleaving actions:

Java 8:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(a, b)
         .peek(System.out::print)
         .limit(b - a) // [a:(b-1)]
         .forEach(i -> System.out.print(","));
```

Java 9:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(a, b)
         .peek(System.out::print)
         .takeWhile(i -> i < b) // [a:(b-1)]
         .forEach(i -> System.out.print(","));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void atob(int a, int b) {
    if (a < b) {
        System.out.print(a);
        while (a < b) {
            a++;
            System.out.print("," + a);
        }
    }
}
```

When called with

```
atob(0,10);
```

Will give the output

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: atob(10,0) will give 10 as output, but should print nothing.

Comment: Thanks for giving me perspective to this!

Answer (score 1):

A general approach could be to make a distinction between the first item and all the others. The first run, no comma is printed BEFORE i. After that, a comma is printed before i, every time.

```
public static void atob(int a,int b) {
    boolean first = true;
    for(int i = a; i <= + b; i++) {
        if ( first == false ) System.out.print(","); 
        System.out.print(i);
        first = false;
    }
}
```

In this specific case, using the ternary operator (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), you could write it as compact as:

```
public static void atob(int a,int b) {
    for(int i = a; i <= + b; i++) {
        System.out.print( i + ( i < b ? "," : "" ) ); 
    }
}
```

Without ternary operation, this would look like this (and is more readable, which is often a good thing):

```
public static void atob(int a,int b) {
    for(int i = a; i <= + b; i++) {
        System.out.print( i ); 
        if ( i < b ) System.out.print( "," );
    }
}
```

(note that + b is the same as b, so you could replace that, as others have done in their answers)

Comment: Thanks for giving me perspective to this!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public static void atob(int a, int b) {
    if (b < a) {
        final int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    } 
    System.out.print(a++);

    for (int i = a; i < b ; i ++ ) {
        System.out.print("," + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me perspective to this!

Answer (score 0):

With slight adjustments (method name, variables, and space after comma):

```
public static void printSequence(int start, int end) {
  if (end < start) {
    return; // or however you want to handle this case
  }
  if (end == start) {
    System.out.print(start);
    return;
  }
  StringBuilder sequence = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    sequence.append(i).append(", ");
  }
  // now simply print the sequence without the last ", "
  System.out.print(sequence.substring(0, sequence.length() - 2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me perspective to this!

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuilder for it. use substring based index.

```
public class arraySort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = { 2, 7, 5, 6, 9, 8, 4, 3, 1 };
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (a[i] < a[j]) {
                    int temp;
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Descending order:{");
        StringBuilder br = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            br.append(a[i] + ",");
        }
        System.out.print( br.substring(0, br.length()-1));
        System.out.println("}");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void atob (int a,int b){
 for(int i = a; i <= b; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print(i );
            if(i<b){
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clunky solution, but hey - it works.

```
public static void atob(int a, int b){
 int count = 1;
  for(int i = a; i <= + b; i++) {
       System.out.print(i);
       if(count!=((b + 1) - a)) {
         System.out.print(", ");
         count++;
       }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, this works too.

```
public static void atob(int a, int b){
 int count = 0;
  for(int i = a; i <= + b; i++) {
    if(count > 0){
      System.out.print(", ");
    }
       System.out.print(i);
      count++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another simple way using regex:

```
String str = "abc, xyz, 123, ";
str = str.replaceAll(", $", "");
System.out.println(str);  // "abc, xyz, 123"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use escape sequence for backspace(\b),outside the main loop,it will delete the last comma.

```
public static void atob(int a,int b)
        {
            for(int i = a; i <= + b; i++) 
            {
                    System.out.print(i + ",");
            }
            System.out.print("\b");
        }
```