# How can I remove the last comma (,) while traversing a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

```java
public class Traverse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node head = new Node(10);
        head.next = new Node(20);
        head.next.next = new Node(30);
        head.next.next.next = new Node(40);
        head.next.next.next.next = new Node(50);
        printList(head);
    }

    public static void printList(Node head) {
        Node curr = head;

        while (curr != null) {
            System.out.print(curr.data);
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
 10,20,30,40,50,
```

I don't want the last commma (`,`).

I am asking this because in a company interview a similar question was asked and logically the traversal is correct but because of the last comma 1 test case failed. I know it's lame but a blunder so the output should be:

```
10,20,30,40,50
```

Comment: You could change the `toString` method in your `Node` class so that it doesn't print the comma if there's no `next` element.  In fact, you could even change it so that it calls the `toString` method on `next` recursively; and that way, you wouldn't need a loop in `printList`.

Comment: You can research similar questions - for example: [Avoid printing the last comma](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9991799/12567365) or [any of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=don't+print+final+comma+site:stackoverflow.com) for more ideas which can be adapted to your specific situation.

Comment: *"so the output is 10,20,30,40,50, "*: eh, not it isn't. There is no comma output in your code.

Comment: @trincot not with the code shown. The question is incomplete as it does not include a [mre]. `Node`, or whatever type `Node#data` is, could add the comma in their `toString()` method.

Comment: @knittl, the question is to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The comma is printed for the same number of times as the numbers. To prevent the last comma from getting printed, a simple if condition should do the trick.

```
 public static void printList(Node head) {
        Node curr = head;

        while (curr != null) {

            System.out.print(curr.data);

            if(curr.next != null)
                System.out.print(",");
           
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }
```

This condition checks whether there is a number after the current number. If there is, a comma is printed, otherwise the comma is not printed for the last number.

P.S Upvote if it helped!

Comment: I assume `curr->next` is a typo caused by too much exposure to C++?