# How to combine more set of ArrayList to 1 set ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've an Arraylist variable

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> nodes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
And
ArrayList<String> split;
```

Then i used `nodes.add(split);`

And I've a result of ArrayList like this

```
[[hasAttribute, hasPart, has_RP-09, has_RP-10], [hasAttribute, hasPart, has_RP-03, has_RP-06]]
```

How to combine that to be a result like this

```
[hasAttribute, hasPart, has_RP-09, has_RP-10, has_RP-03, has_RP-06]
```

Thank you guys for the answer.

Comment: If the same value exists in both ArrayLists are they only added once to the COMBINED result ? Do they have to be in any specific order ?

Comment: So you want the union of two (or more) `ArrayList<String>` objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Join two arrays in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583521/join-two-arrays-in-java)

Comment: if you need all elements in one ArrayList. use Set<String> node=new HashSet();. and add node.addAll(split);

Comment: If you are going to combine them into a single array why do you keep them in separate arrays ? whay not add them to a single SET from the beginning ?

Comment: Thank you all guys for every answer , i got it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the individual list and add all of its elements to a `Set`:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> nodes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
...
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
for (ArrayList<String> list : nodes) {
    set.addAll(list);       
}
```

If you want to preserve the order, use a `LinkedHashSet` instead of the `HashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 can help you a lot.

```
Set<String> combined = nodes.stream().flatMap(n -> n.stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```