# How do I split the rest of the URL from the last path of it

Tags: java, file, url, uri, file-uri

I have this file URL: `http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/resources/upload/2014/09/02/new sample.pdf` which will be converted to `http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/resources/upload/2014/09/02/new%20sample.pdf` later.

Now I can get the last path by:

```
public static String getLastPathFromUrl(String url) {
    return url.replaceFirst(".*/([^/?]+).*", "$1");
}
```

which will give me `new sample.pdf`

but how do I get the remaining of the URL: `http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/resources/upload/2014/09/02/`
?

Comment: How about [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) and [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))?

Answer (score 4):

Easier way to get last path from URL would be to use String.split function, like this:-

```
String url = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/resources/upload/2014/09/02/new sample.pdf";
String[] urlArray = url.split("/");
String lastPath = urlArray[urlArray.length-1];
```

This converts your url into an Array which can then be used in many ways. There are various ways to get url-lastPath, one way could be to join the above generated Array using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978933/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-join-array-elements-with-a-separator-the-oposite-of-spl) answer. Or use lastIndexOf() and substring like this:-

```
String restOfUrl = url.substring(0,url.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

PS:- Although you can learn something by doing this but I think your best solution would be to replace space by %20 in the complete url String, that would be the fastest and make more sense.

Comment: I already have successfully replaced every white space to %20 and also getting the last path of the URL ONLY. What I want to get is the remaining part of the URL, not the last path.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood it correctly but when you say

> I have this file URL: URL/**new sample.pdf** which will be converted to URL/**new%20sample.pdf** later.

It looks like you are trying to replace "space" with %20 in URL or said in simple words trying to take care of unwanted characters in URL. If that is what you need use pre-built

URLEncoder.encode(String url,String enc), You can us ÜTF-8 as encoding.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

If you really need to split it, assuming that you interested in URL after http://, remove http:// and take store remaining URL in string variable called  say remainingURL. then use

> List myList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(remainingURL.split("/")));

You can iterate on myList to get rest of URL fragments.

Comment: I only took successfully the last path of the URL, what I want to have is the remaining portion of the whole URL, not the last path.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it:

```
    File file=new File("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/resources/upload/2014/09/02/new sample.pdf");
    System.out.println(file.getPath().replaceAll(file.getName(),""));
```

Output:
`http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/resources/upload/2014/09/02/`

Answer (score 0):

Spring solution:

```
List<String> pathSegments = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url).build().getPathSegments();
String lastPath = pathSegments.get(pathSegments.size()-1);
```