# Java - Create a delimiter string from string array

Tags: java

What's the best way to convert a string array to a delimiter separated string.

**eg**:

`String[] arr =  {"apple","orange","banana","round"};` -------> apple-orange-banana-round?

Comment: apple-orange-banana-round is **a** String?

Comment: Create a StringBuffer, loop `arr` and append each word to the StringBuffer

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978933/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-join-array-elements-with-a-separator-the-opposite-of-sp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StringBuffer or StringBuilder (StringBuffer is thread safe) to make this:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for(String s : arr){
    sb.append(s + "-");
}
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
return sb.toString();
```

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: It will work and I did think of this solution. Is this the best solution of this (common) problem?