# Android Studio build failed with jdk1.8.0_66

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

Every time i run app in android studio. I have received a bug from Message Gradle Build:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

This is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.redimed.telehealth.patient"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 21
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("Telehealth.keystore")
            storePassword "redimed1234567"
            keyAlias "REDIMED"
            keyPassword "REDIMED"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'io.socket:socket.io-client:0.6.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
}
```

Comment: please show your gradle

Comment: How about an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Android studio not support some of the features of Java 1.8.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528782/is-jdk-1-8-fully-supported-by-android-studio

Comment: Do you plan on using [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda)? If not, you need to use JDK 1.7

Comment: As I know, on Android developer site, they suggest using JDK 1.7 http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements