# i can't set JDK 1.8 in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8

I have downloaded and installed jdk 1.8, but when i try to set path to jdk 1.8 in ProjectStructure -> JDK Location, AndroidStudio ignored it, so after set path 
[image]
click OK and reopen window "ProjectStructure" i see jdk 1.7 again
[image]

Comment: Did you try to resolve the error shown in the bottom? Maybe it doesn't accept new settings if you do not change this?

Comment: @Bernhard, No, this warning is useless, AS worked fine before i update buildTools to 24.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I deleted folder with java 1.7, and AndroidStudio open me dialog for specifing jdk-path, whehe i set it. Thank everybody for answering!

Comment: It works ! thanks @Werder. 
note:  you should install JDK 1.8 first, you must **delete** not just rename the java 1.7 folder

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug either in Android Studio 2.1.x or IntelliJ. Here is a workaround after you installed the new JDK and set it as `JAVA_HOME` env variable:

1. Close Android Studio
2. Go to `%HOME%/.AndroidStudio2.1/config/options` (or which version you are using)
3. rename/delete `jdk.table.xml`
4. start Android Studio again -> the JDK set in `JAVA_HOME` should be set as default jdk

Reference: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213239

See also: [Android Studio JDK location changes back to 1.7 every time it is updated to 1.8 path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066957/android-studio-jdk-location-changes-back-to-1-7-every-time-it-is-updated-to-1-8/38067170)

Comment: This still not help. There is always the previous value in the jdk path.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Java JDK7 and install JDK8, or set JDK8 as default Java VM in your OS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your path variable and add your jdk location to it . Studio must be automatically getting path from your environment variable and replacing your path .

Answer (score 0):

The JDK 1.8 does not seem to be fully supported by Android Studio because the Android platform does not support Java 8 as it is currently.

You can see this link for more information. [Is JDK 1.8 fully supported by Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528782/is-jdk-1-8-fully-supported-by-android-studio)

Comment: No, i use AndroidStudio 2.1.3, and i have error: Error:Buildtools 24.0.1 requires Java 1.8 or above. Current JDK version is 1.7.

Comment: There might be an other issue then. Buildtools 24.0.1 should not require Java 8. Looks like preview version of Android N has support for Java 8 https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html

Could you add your gradle files for debugging reference?

Answer (score 0):

use Android Studio 2.2 preview 7 version this only support java 8

Then you can use java 8 features :)

Answer (score 0):

Just move your sdk folder to the small destination folder like C:/sdk. It seems that without setting your sdk folder you can't change the directory of the jdk folder.