# Using ResultSetMetaData to frame SQL query

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am trying to use ResultSetMetaData to frame a SQL query for checking if there are duplicate records in a table dynamically.

The query for checking duplicate records will look like this

```
select 
col1,
col2,
col3
from Table A
group by 
col1,
col2,
col3
having count(*)>1
```

Most of this code is boilerplate and i can extract all the columns of the table using ResultSetMetaData. But I am not sure how to do this in an elegant way and handle the last missing comma.

Comment: tried running the query ?

Comment: @utility : Yes . This query returns an empty result set if there are no duplicate records in table.

Comment: You can save execution time by first checking whether the table is defined with a unique key (DatabaseMetaData). If comma is such a problem, use `, 1 as Smrt` and `, Smrt` or such.

Comment: This seems to be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978933/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-join-array-elements-with-a-separator-the-opposite-of-sp

Comment: What do you mean with "frame a SQL query"?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use [Joiner](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) from the Guava Libraries in these kind of situation. With joiner you could write something like

```
String.format(
  "select %1$s from table %s group by %1$s having count(*) > 1",
  "tablename",
  Joiner.on(",").join("col1","col2","col3")
);
```

If you are using Java 8 then you can use [String.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) instead.

Please do check that the tablenames are properly quoted if necessary.