# How to get desired format from ArrayList

Tags: java

```
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Test {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);
    private static DecimalFormat decimal_inpoints = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException,
            ParseException {

        ArrayList<Integer> array_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        array_list.add(1);
        array_list.add(0);

        String joinedString = array_list.toString();

        System.out.println(joinedString);

    }

}
```

How can i get output as  1,0

When i used array_list.toString(); its giving putput as [1,0] (array added )

Could you please tell me How to get 1,0 instead of [1,0]

Comment: The simplest way is to perform the "joining" operation yourself... have you tried doing that? (Use a StringBuilder, appending an item then a comma, etc.) Also note that your code doesn't do anything that would generate an UnknownHostException or a ParseException, nor do you use the logger or DecimalFormat. All of that can be removed from your code, to make it simpler to see what you're interested in.

Comment: This is the default implementation of `toString()` of `ArrayList` class. Your have to write your own method to get string in desired format which you can easily do using StringBuilder.

Comment: You should check this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978933/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-join-array-elements-with-a-separator-the-opposite-of-sp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978933/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-join-array-elements-with-a-separator-the-opposite-of-sp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simpliest way is;

```
array_list.toString().replace("[","").replace("]","");
```

Comment: string.replace() is not exist in java 7 ? I'm really surprised. EDIT: just checked out java 7 docs and I see there is string.replace() method. how is that possible you cannot use it ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 6):

#### Using [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/):

```
String join = StringUtils.join(joinList, ",");
```

#### Using Java 8

```
String joined = String.join(",", list);
```

#### Using Google [Guava (Joiner)](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained)

```
Joiner joiner = Joiner.on(",");
String join = joiner.join(joinList);
```

#### Using StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(array_list.size());
boolean isFirst = true;
for (int i : array_list){
  if (isFirst) {
    builder.append(i);
    isFirst = false;
  } else {
    builder.append(", " + i);
  }
}
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8 you can do it with the joining Collector:

```
    String joinedString = list.stream()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Java 8. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978933/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-join-array-elements-with-a-separator-the-opposite-of-sp)

```
private toStringNoBrackets(ArrayList MyList) {
    return String.join(",", MyList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own class and override the toString method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyIntegerArrayList extends ArrayList<Integer>
{
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return super.toString().replace("[","").replace("]","");
    }
}


MyIntegerArrayList myIntegerArrayList = new MyIntegerArrayList();
myIntegerArrayList.add(0);
myIntegerArrayList.add(1);
myIntegerArrayList.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class SOPlayground {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> array_list = new ArrayList<>();
        array_list.add(1);
        array_list.add(0);

        StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ");
        array_list.stream().forEach((i) -> {
            sj.add(i.toString());
        });
        System.out.println(sj.toString());
    }

}
```

Output:

```
1, 0
```