# java write the output in comma delimited format

Tags: java, apache

How to write the below output in comma delimited format.Please help on this.

```
logger.info("total count of ReportGen requests with size <100kB: "+countlt200);
logger.info("# of Non-ReportGEN Requests: "+countNON);
logger.info("total response time of ReportGen requests with size >=100kB: "+gt200ReportGen);
logger.info("total response time of ReportGen requests with size <100kB: "+lt200ReportGen);
logger.info("total response time of all non ReportGen requests: "+nonReportResTime);
logger.info("total size of ReportGen requests with size <100kB: "+lt200ResTime);
logger.info("total size of ReportGen requests with size >=100kB: "+gt200ResTime);
logger.info("total size of all non ReportGen requests: "+nonReportGenSize);
```

Comment: Dude... what is `logger`?

Comment: logger for to see the out put instead of system out println

Comment: What is it an instance of?

Comment: Are you using java 8?

Answer (score 2):

If I guess correctly, you want to make only one output, which is comma separated.

If you are using Java 8 you could use the `String.join()` method (see [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26195047/1943228)).

Or you could use a `StringBuilder` or just `concatenation`.
Here an example with a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

stringBuilder.append("total count of ReportGen requests with size <100kB: "+ countlt200);
stringBuilder.append(", # of Non-ReportGEN Requests: "+countNON);
stringBuilder.append(", total response time of ReportGen requests with size >=100kB: "+gt200ReportGen);

// or if you want it more readable for you 
stringBuilder.append("something..something");
stringBuilder.append(",");
stringBuilder.append("something..something");
stringBuilder.append(",");

// aso

logger.info(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringJoiner:

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(SEPARATOR);
joiner.add(value);
joiner.toString();
```