# JAVA - Parsing math expressions

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I need to parse a math expression in Java.
Currently, I'm using **JEP** library (2.23 free version) , which provides a parser that allows a large set of operations. However, I need to also perform operations over arrays, such as mean, sum, max, ...
I had a look to the **mXparser** library: it provides such operations, but arrays are not currently supported. Precisely, all the values in the array have to be explicitly specified; e.g.

```
Expression e = new Expression("mean(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)");
```

Is there a similar library able to work with arrays?
I'd like something like this:

```
Expression e = new Expression("mean(array)");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `String expression = "mean(" + StringUtils.join(arrayObj,"','") + ")";` and then `Expression e = new Expression(expression)`. more on stringutils check http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Iterator,%20char%29

Comment: Great! It allows overcoming the lack of array management of the mXparser library. Thank you, so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1978933/1661938