# Iterates through the array x using a for loop. Returns the elements of x as a String where each element is separated by a single space

Tags: java, arrays, string, int, tostring

```
public static String toStringFor(){

    int[] x={3, 45, 17, 2, -1, 44, 9, 23, 67, 2, -6, -23, -100, 12, 5, 1212};

    String array = x.toString();

    return array;
}
```

I keep getting

> [I@62aba879

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A quick and easy way to join array elements with a separator (the opposite of split) in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978933/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-join-array-elements-with-a-separator-the-opposite-of-sp)

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is the hashcode of the array instance. You can't simply use `toString()` on an array and expect to give you a nice result. In fact, each object has its own `toString()` method that can be implemented in various ways. This is how the implementation of `toString()` on an array looks like:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

You will have to iterate through the elements and create the final string yourself. Here's a way to do it in Java 8:

```
int[] x={3, 45, 17, 2, -1, 44, 9, 23, 67, 2, -6, -23, -100, 12, 5, 1212};

String result = Arrays.stream(x)
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println("result = " + result);
```

This creates a stream of values from your array and collects them into a String separated with space.

Another version with a for loop:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
for (int i : x) {
    sj.add(String.valueOf(i));
}
System.out.println("result =" + sj.toString());
```

You can also iterate the array using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
...
}
```

[As seen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42775715/1667977).

Comment: @SkrewEverything Then my day just got even better ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a **for** and **StringJoiner**(credits to @sm4) to help with that purpose

```
public static String toStringFor(){

    int[] x={3, 45, 17, 2, -1, 44, 9, 23, 67, 2, -6, -23, -100, 12, 5, 1212};


    StringJoiner sj=new StringJoiner(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        sj.add(String.valueOf(x[i]));
    }

    return sj.toString();
}
```

Comment: But he needs a string which is separated by a space. We should iterate through all elements to construct the string.

Comment: In that case, he would use a for to go trought every element on array and concat it on a new String or StringBuilder

Comment: I said so that you will update your answer and you are literally saying what I said.

Comment: While you can use StringBuilder, I would not recommend it. First, you are using it kind of wrong, since you are also using a String concatenation. The compiler will probably deal with it just fine, but you are creating some extra String instances when doing sb.append("a" + "b"). Second, you will have a trailing space in the result. Look at my answer and consider using StringJoiner (either directly or through a collector on a stream).

Comment: @sm4 You're right, i'll edit my answer. Didn't know about StringJoiner, each day gets betters since I'm here on StackOverflow haha, thanks guys. Always learning i guess ^^

Answer (score 0):

`toString` returns a string holding some abbreviation characters followed by the hexadecimal representation of a hash, unless overridden. Arrays don't override this, so you got the `toString` of the object that the array is.

You need to write custom code to accomplish your goal. Perhaps you could loop through the array, appending the `String` representation of each array element to a `StringBuilder` along with some characters for formatting, and output the `toString` of the resulting `StringBuilder` from your method that performs that task.

Comment: @Alberto Pérez offers the more utilitarian answer. This answer is more pedagogical.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that you're calling `toString()` on the array object - not on the elements within the array.

Use `Arrays.toString(int[] a)` instead.

In order to generate a string representation of the array, which is separated by space, it helps, if you handle the first array item independently and then add all further elements prefixed by a space.

```
    int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    int i = 0;
    String arr = String.valueOf(x[i++]);
    for (; i < x.length; i++)
        arr += " " + x[i];
```

Doing so leaves no trailing space at the end of the string.