# Regular expression - replace text ignoring text from round brackets

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following information:

a). a String in this format `[name(label)] bla [name2(label2)] bla [name3(bla3)]`

b). Strings `name` and `name2`

I need to replace `[name(label)]` and `[name2(label2)]` (anything can be between round brackets) with another string (say `*`), so the result needs to be `* bla * bla [name3(bla3)]`

**Input**

`[name(label)] bla [name2(label2)] bla [name3(bla3)]`

`name` and `name2`

**Output**

`* bla * bla [name3(bla3)]`

How can I do that using regex in Java?

Comment: input and output example

Comment: Should `name` and `label` have the same number at the end, or was it just an example?

Comment: Java language. `name` and `label` doesn't need to have the same number at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\[(name|name2)(\(.*?\))?\]
```

and replace by your desired thing say *

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fVTQjy/16)

Java Sample:

```
String regex = "\\[(name|name2)(\\(.*?\\)\\)?]";
String string = "[name(label)] bla [name2(label2)] bla [name3(bla3)]\n";
String result = string.replaceAll(regex,"*");
System.out.println(result);
```

Javascript Sample:

```js
const regex = /\[(name|name2)(\(.*?\))?\]/gm;
const str = `[name(label)] bla [name2(label2)] bla [name3(bla3)]  [name] [name2]`;
const subst = `*`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: works! can this be improved to replace also `[name]` and `[name2]`  (without having those round brackets) with that character `*`?

Comment: Thanks. There is a small correction that needs to be done to the regex: delete last `\\` - I could not edit your post.

Answer (score 2):

regex: **"\[name2?\([^\)]+\)\]"**

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class ValidateDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] inputA = new String[] {"name", "name2"};
        String tmp = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < inputA.length; i++)
        {
            if(i>0)
                tmp+="|";
            tmp+=inputA[i];
        }
        tmp = "("+tmp+")";
/*
        System.out.println(tmp);
        System.exit(0);
*/
        String regex = "\\["+tmp+"\\([^\\)]+\\)\\]";
        String input = "[name(label)] bla [name2(label2)] bla [name3(bla3)]\n";
        String output = input.replaceAll(regex,"*");
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Better, thanks. Note that you reimplemented [`String.join`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26195047/6419007).

Comment: @EricDuminil there is no String.join in java 1.7 :(