# string sends command name instead of text after command

Tags: java, plugins, command, bukkit

so I'm trying to do broadcast command but it sends out the command name I don't know why? if you have any idea why and how to solve this problem

```
package ml.harrytubestudios.helloworld.commands;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;

import ml.harrytubestudios.helloworld.main;

public class bro implements CommandExecutor {
private main plugins;
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String no, String[] args) {
 
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage(no);
return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: probably because the value of that String is not what you expect it to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems here are twofold. If you look at the documentation for [`CommandExecutor`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/command/CommandExecutor.html); it's the same in Spigot as in Bukkit, you'll see that it says for `onCommand`:

> If false is returned, then the "usage" plugin.yml entry for this command (if defined) will be sent to the player.

Because you're returning `false`, you're saying that the command wasn't entered correctly and the usage string should be sent to the `CommandSender`. You should return true if the command executed successfully.

However, you should still see your `broadcastMessage`, which you are. This is explained again in the documentation as it says for the 3rd argument (`label`):

> Alias of the command which was used

This means that you are broadcasting the alias of the command (your `no` parameter) that the `CommandSender` used, rather than their arguments, which is what I presume you're after.

In order to get the arguments of the command used, you'll want the `args` parameter which is an array of Strings. You'll probably want to format this into one string for use with your broadcast; for which there are different [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26195047/11916773).

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer its that string is the command and the args is the arguments after the command so

```
    package ga.harrytubestudios.helloworld.commands;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

import ga.harrytubestudios.helloworld.main;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.chat.ComponentBuilder;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.chat.HoverEvent;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.chat.TextComponent;

public class shopcommand implements CommandExecutor {
private main pluign;
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender Sender, Command smd, String label, String[] args) {
        
    
            Player p = (Player)Sender;
p.sendmessgae(args[0])
 


}
```