# My reverse a string code includes a space at the end of the string

Tags: java

I am a beginner of Java, and would like to reverse the character order of a sentence when I input some words as command line arguments.

Here is my code. When I input "This is a pen.", the output should be ".nep a si sihT". However, the output of this code is ".nep a si sihT ". It includes an extra space at the end of the reversed sentence.

Does anyone know how can I delete the space?

```
public class Reverse {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i = args.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            for(int j = args[i].length() - 1; j >= 0; j--){
                System.out.print(args[i].charAt(j));
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: This is effectively just an instance of [joining an array (of reversed strings) with a separator (space)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978933/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-join-array-elements-with-a-separator-the-opposite-of-sp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid space at end by adding a if statement which skips last iteration

```java
public class Reverse {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i = args.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            for(int j = args[i].length() - 1; j >= 0; j--){
                System.out.print(args[i].charAt(j));
            }
            if(i != 0){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure that leading and trailing spaces are inconsequential to your subsequent logic, you can just apply the function `trim()` to your result.

`trim()` doesn't affect middle spaces, so the rest of your logic should still pan out fine.

You can also save your string in a variable and print it out just once - at the end of your logic. All in all, your logic would look like this:

```
public class Reverse {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String res = "";
        for(int i = args.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            for(int j = args[i].length() - 1; j >= 0; j--){
                res += args[i].charAt(j);
            }
            res += " ";
        }
        System.out.print(res.trim());
    }
}
```